# Rust: use IntoIterator inside generalized function

Tags: rust, iterator

When I do cycle as

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![1,2].into_iter().cycle();
    assert_eq!(a.next().unwrap(), 1);
    assert_eq!(a.next().unwrap(), 2);
    assert_eq!(a.next().unwrap(), 1);
    assert_eq!(a.next().unwrap(), 2);
}
```

it works well as I expect.
But when I try to write generalized function as

```
pub fn cycle_generalized_func<T>(into_iter: T) -> impl Iterator<Item = T::Item>
where
    T: IntoIterator,
    T::Item: Clone,
{
    into_iter.into_iter().cycle()
}
```

And try to use as

```
let mut a = cycle(vec![1,2]);
```

id does not compline and produce errors on *into_iter.into_iter().cycle()* row like:

> the trait bound `<T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter: Clone` is not satisfied
> the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `<T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter`rustcE0277
> iterator.rs(3270, 23): required by a bound in `std::iter::Iterator::cycle`
> main.rs(6, 19): consider further restricting the associated type: `, <T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter: Clone`

What do I do wrong? I have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of [`Iterator::cycle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cycle) is:

```rust
fn cycle(self) -> Cycle<Self>ⓘ
where
    Self: Clone
```

That is, it requires the iterator itself to be `: Clone`, not the `Item`. To fix your code, replace `T::Item: Clone` with `T::IntoIter: Clone`.

This compiles for me:

```rust
pub fn cycle_generalized_func<T>(into_iter: T) -> impl Iterator<Item = T::Item>
where
    T: IntoIterator,
    T::IntoIter: Clone,
{
    into_iter.into_iter().cycle()
}
```

---

If you need this to work with iterators that are not `Clone` but the items are, you'll have to collect all items into a container like `Vec` first:

```rust
pub fn cycle_generalized_func<T>(into_iter: T) -> impl Iterator<Item = T::Item>
where
    T: IntoIterator,
    T::Item: Clone,
{
    into_iter
        .into_iter()
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .into_iter()
        .cycle()
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right!
By the way, what shall i do if i have to have  `Item` to be Clone, not `IntoIter`?

Comment: `IntoIter` must be `Clone` because that's how `cycle` works: it keeps two copies of the iterator, yields elements from the second copy, and clones the original one whenever the second one finishes. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/iter/adapters/cycle.rs.html.

Comment: If your iterator cannot be cloned, you'll have to collect all its elements into e.g. a `Vec` and call `cycle` on that.

Comment: I have added a solution for when the iterator is not `Clone` but item is. Note that this might use a lot of memory as all elements will be collected into a `Vec` up-front.